# Android: Displaying a list in a fragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a existing fragment, in which i want to display typical address kind of information like Street, City, PIN and List of Phone Numbers.

To display List of Phone Numbers, i added listview in addressfragment.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStreetAddr"
            style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:text="default" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/phones"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp" >
        </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My fragment class:

```
        public class AddressFragment extends Fragment {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtStreetAddr)).setText(
                        "123, Corner Street");

                ListView phoneListView = ((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phones));

                ArrayList<String> phNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                phNumbers.add("4343534343");
                phNumbers.add("6767566766");

                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyApp.getAppContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, phNumbers);
                // Set The Adapter
                phoneListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
    return rootView;
        }
```

*The phone list view just does not show up on the screen - Why?*
Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Post ur layout xml file completely

Comment: and post also the complete onCreateView. Post also the complete layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forget to inflate `View` in `onCreateView(...)`

```
View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
```

add your `onCreateView(...)` should be

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View rootView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtStreetAddr)).setText(
                "123, Corner Street");

        ListView phoneListView =((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phones);

        ArrayList<String> phNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
        phNumbers.add("4343534343");
        phNumbers.add("6767566766");

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, phNumbers);
        // Set The Adapter
        phoneListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

     return rootView;
  }
```

Comment: that could have explained a runtime crash or a compile time error, not a *the list is not showing up* error,

Comment: Sorry this was partial code...the inflater is indeed there (code updated in question), as i street address shows up correctly

Comment: @Jasper also used `getActivity()` instead of `MyApp.getAppContext()`

Comment: MD> Yes, after i using getActivity() the listview is showing up - But i only see ONE row in list.. just the first row.

Comment: @Jasper Something problem with your `ListView` position in XML check it.

Comment: Apparently ListView inside ScrollView will not show all records - so that is why we see only one record now.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `ScrollView` and make the `LinearLayout` as the parent layout.

Comment: Thanks Chandrakanth...that does take care of the one record issue. If you know any address widgets or a better way to handle this please do post...!

Answer (score 0):

if you've scrollview as parent view then, you've to set listview height programmatically, you can create a method, like below---

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {

        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

then pass listview to this method like below --

```
phoneListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(phoneListView);
```

Hope this will work perfectly.